# The general solution of $\tan(x) = \tan(2x-π/2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The general solution given by the teacher is $$x = \fracπ2 + kπ.$$

But to me, this solution is wrong because $\tan(π/2)$ has an indeterminate value (infinite). How do I know that one infinity is equal to the other? It has no sense.

Therefore, I would put that it has no solution for the real values. Am I correct?

Comment: $\tan{(2x-\frac{\pi}{2})}=-\tan{(\frac{\pi}{2}-2x)}=-\frac{1}{\tan{2x}}$

Comment: You raise a very good point. I agree with your observations. What the teacher claims is incorrect.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Just a slight correction, $\tan(π/2)$ is not indeterminate or infinity, it is rather undefined.

Comment: Right, the equation has no solution. $\cot(x)=\cot(2x-\frac\pi2)$ does.

Answer (score 2):

The solution you were presented is surely wrong, or at least would require further explanation of context. It does not make sense to have a solution outside the domain of definition of the involved expressions. The two graphs never intersect and there is no solution to the equation.

Answer (score 1):

If you set $t=\tan x$ and apply the duplication formula for the tangent, you  have
$$\tan\Bigl(2x-\frac \pi 2\Bigr)=-\frac 1{\tan 2x}=\frac{t^2-1}{2t},$$
so the equation becomes
$$\frac{t^2-1}{2t}=t\iff t^2-1=2t^2\iff t^2=-1,$$
which has no real solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan{(2x-\frac{\pi}{2})}=-\tan{(\frac{\pi}{2}-2x)}=-\frac{1}{\tan{2x}}$$
$$\tan{x}=-\frac{1}{\tan{2x}}\rightarrow\tan{x}\tan{2x}=-1$$
$$\tan{x}\frac{2\tan{x}}{1-\tan^2{x}}=-1\rightarrow2\tan^2{x}=-1+\tan^2{x}\rightarrow\tan^2{x}=-1!$$
Somthing is wrong in the problem!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the problem. It's just that the equation has no real solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are halfway there with your approach. Note that $\tan(x)$ has period $\pi$, so if $x + \pi = 2x - \pi/2$, then $\tan(x) = \tan(x + \pi) = \tan(2x - \pi/2)$ as well.

Extending this idea to shifting $\tan(x)$ by $k$ periods left/right, where $k$ is any integer, we need that $x + k \pi = 2x - \pi/2 \implies k \pi + \pi/2 = x$. But $\tan(k \pi + \pi/2) = \tan(\pi/2)$ by periodicity, which is undefined!

Hence there is no solution for $x$ (the empty set).

Comment: Note that you could very well write $x = 2(x + k \pi/2) - \pi/2$ instead, where the period of $\tan 2x$ is $\pi/2$ (why?). This gives $x = 2x + k \pi - \pi / 2 \implies \pi/2 - k \pi = x$, which gives the same result.